# Why sometimes Ruby mistakes hash literals with blocks

Tags: ruby, syntax

This works:

```
[1, 2].inject({}) do |result, item| end
```

This also works:

```
[1, 2].inject Hash.new do |result, item| end
```

This throws a SyntaxError:

```
[1, 2].inject {} do |result, item| end
```

In which cases hash literal `{}` and `Hash.new` are not interchangeable?

Comment: There are two camps on whether or not we should use parenthesis to delimit the parameters to a method. This is one of the times when not using them runs into trouble. I don't like this sort of error, and, because I've caromed off many other languages in my career, I use parenthesis on almost every method call. `[1, 2].inject({}) do |result, item| end` is how I'd do it.

Comment: Ruby is not making mistakes, you are  making mistakes.

Comment: Yes, ruby is making mistakes. I can fix the ruby interpreter to recognize the last statement correctly.

Comment: If taking `{}` as an empty block is not syntactically valid, why the parser cannot just tries to parse it as an empty hash instead of throwing a SyntaxError?

Comment: Ethan You are more than welcome to contribute to the Ruby parser. Go to it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Any method may be called with an optional block.
- A block may have the form `do |params| ... end` or the form `{ |params| ... }`

  - *It is idiomatic within the Ruby community to use the former for multiline blocks and the latter for single-line blocks.*
- Blocks do not have to accept parameters, in which case they can actually appear as either `do ... end` or `{ ... }`.
- Thus `foo {}` could be interpreted as either a method taking an empty Hash as an argument, i.e. `foo({})` or as a method that is being passed an empty block, similar to `foo{ |x| }` or `foo{ nil }`. Ruby opts to interpret it as the former, which leaves your example as a method taking two blocks, which is not syntactically valid.

Since you seem not to be aware of the more terse block syntax, you could use it like so:

```
squares = [1,2,3,4,5].map{ |x| x*x } #=> [1,4,9,16,25]
```

And here's a (not-very useful) example of the legal empty block syntax:

```
p [1,2,3].map{} #=> [nil,nil,nil]
```

The block has no statements, and so the value of the last expression in the block is `nil`, to which each value in the block is mapped.

Comment: If a method takes two blocks, shouldn't be a comma `,` between the two blocks, like so `foo {}, {}`? Seems like a ruby interpreter bug to me.

Comment: @Ethan: `f {}, {}` would be a method being called with two empty Hashes as arguments. There's ambiguity and Ruby has to resolve the ambiguity, that it resolves the ambiguity in a way that you don't like isn't a bug, it is just they way it goes.